# Подклинивает анимация в qml

Tags: qt, qml

Немного, но неприятно, подклинивает qml-анимированный спинер. Реализован как `Image + PropertyAnimation`. Замена на `AnimatedImage` с gif-изображением ничего не дала. 
Что ещё можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено при помощи Qml-компонента [RotationAnimator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rotationanimator.html). Все потомки [Animator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animator.html) выполняются в render-потоке qml и не блокируются UI-потоком.